# Is there a way to execute a list(List<ObjectId> id) to find documents that match the list?

Tags: mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm persisting the data on a MongoDB Database using Panache repository strategy.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class ProductRepository implements PanacheMongoRepository<Product> {}
```

Assume that I have a collection with the following data on it.

```
|id  | name | price |
|1   | p1   | $ 1.00|
|2   | p2   | $ 2.00|
|3   | p3   | $ 3.00|
|4   | p4   | $ 4.00|
```

And I have a `List<ObjectId> productsToRetrieve` with [1, 3]

and the expected result from a query would be:

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 | $ 1.00 |
| 3 | p3 | $ 3.00 |

Here's what I've tried

```java
find("id", productsToRetrieve);
find("id = ?1", productsToRetrieve);
list("id", productsToRetrieve);
Document query = new Document();
find(new Document("id", new Document("$in", productsId))).list();
```

I could use a `forEach` to retrieve each product from the repository and add to a list, but that's not a good approach. A PanacheQL query would solve the problem, but I don't know how to.

Comment: I haven't used quarkus but mongo query you need is using `$in`. Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yAuQZCeQr1U) example. Hope it helps. According to [docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache) try something like: `id in ?1, ?3`

Comment: That solved! Just instead of `id` I used ` _id`

Comment: @JohnnesSouza if you solved it, can you answer your own question so other could have a clear answer in case they have the same issue ?

Comment: I will wait a little longer to see if @J.F. will post an aswer, since his comment helped me to solve the issue. But tks for the update!

Comment: Thanks for advising. I've post the answer. Hope it helps for something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired output is necessary to use `$in`. Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yAuQZCeQr1U).

And using quarkus, according to [docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache), it says:

> status in ?1 will be mapped to {'status':{$in: [?1]}}

So the necessary query is:

```
_id in ?1, ?3
```